# What approach should I use in the DAO to manipulate data in a database using Room?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, rx-java2, android-livedata

For now I use this code in my DAO:

```
@Dao
interface NotesDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Notes")
    fun getAllNotes(): List<Notes?>?

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Notes WHERE not hidden AND not grouped")
    fun getNotes(): List<Notes?>?

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Notes WHERE id = :id")
    fun getById(id: Long): Notes?

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(notes: Notes?)

    @Update
    fun update(notes: Notes?)

    @Delete
    fun delete(notes: Notes?)
}
```

But in many tutorials I either see `Flowable<List<Notes>>` instead of `List<Notes>` or `LiveData<List<Notes>>`.
Which approach is preferable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two factors you should consider:

1. All interactions with database (both queries and updates) should be outside main thread.
2. In some use-cases you want single "one-shot" query, in other - you want your query to be "live" - i.e. to return updated result whenever data was changed (Observer pattern).

Using Kotlin you have two main options (what's better is a matter of taste. In some tutorials you can see also AsyncTask or Thread executors for switching off the main thread):

1. Use RxJava (use **Flowable** for "live" queries, **Single** - for "one-shot" queries and one of the **Single/Completable/Maybe** for insert/update/delete). Using RxJava you can use built-in mechanism for switching off the main thread.
2. Use Coroutines (and keyword `suspend`) for insert/update/delete, and **LiveData** or **Flow** (from coroutines library) for "live" queries, or `suspend` - for "one-shot" queries. `suspend` lets to switch from the main thread. If you use LiveData/Flow you don't need `suspend`, since Room does it itself.

See also [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#return-types) for additional hints.

Comment: Thx, now I kinda get it. But do Flowable and LiveData(or Flow) have the same performance? Or in this case it doesn't matter?

Comment: It's more about stack you choose to use in a project in general for async work (db, network and so on). Decision is opinionated. In last Google's tutorials they used Flow in Dao and in ViewModel they turn it into LiveData. But nobody say it's the only and the best way.